# Java Scanner Delimiter - Extracting Multiple Sub-strings From a Single String

Tags: java, string, io, split

I have searched nearly all pages on Stackoverflow but still have not found out how to do this. I have the following string (which is being parsed from file):

```
f:   (matchQuan
     (Recipe
     (Unique FoodType "slurpee" "xxx-xxx-eee-ddd")) 
     (Unique IngredType "slurpee" "qqq-rrr-sss") "slurpee" 
     (Cup-Vol 12)).
```

Now, I want to parse this string again and extract the string `matchQuan`, the `slurpee`, the string `Unique` and `FoodType` and `Recipe` and the ID numbers i.e. `xxx-xxx-eee-ddd`.

How would I do something like this with multiple extractions from a single string? I can't use `Scanner.next()` I don't believe because it advances to the next token in string.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by extract? you want to sub-string?

Comment: you can use `Scanner.next()` to iterate over your string tokens and store them in a container like List<List<String>> then if the format doesn't change you can get `matchQuan` by doing `list.get(0).get(0)`. Do you see where I'm going with this?

Comment: Yes, sorry for being unclear. I was to produce multiple individual substrings from this String.

Comment: @Adrian within the first quotations (i.e. slurpee) there is no guarantee that it will always be a single word. So simply using `.next` wouldn't always produce the result i wanted. How would I handle this?

Comment: @RichieEpiscopo I don't think you understood what I said before. You should store your data in a `List` of some type and not use `.next()` all the time. Or try making a small DFA to parse your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this help for you?

```
public static void getString() {
    String str = "f:   (matchQuan " +
                      "(Recipe "+
                      "(Unique FoodType" + " slurpee"+ " xxx-xxx-eee-ddd"+
                      "(Unique IngredType"+ " slurpee"+ " qqq-rrr-sss"+" slurpee" +
                       " (Cup - Vol 12)).";
    String newStr=str.replaceAll("\\(","").replaceAll("\\)","");
    String[] arrStr=newStr.split(" ");
    for (int i=0;i<arrStr.length;i++){
        System.out.println(arrStr[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Tell me if you are looking a different thing. I got your question this way

Comment: Oh, this really opened my eyes to the `split()` method -- I didn't know that existed before. I am going to use this in my implementation. One question: Why is this line required: `newStr=str.replaceAll("\\(","").replaceAll("\\)","");`?

Comment: To remove () brackets

Comment: @RichieEpiscopo is this the answer you are looking?